# Installing MediaWiki with Docker

Tags: docker, mediawiki

I'm attempting to install MediaWiki using the Docker image mediawiki:1.40.0-fpm. It's my intention to use an external instance of Nginx as reverse proxy for SSL termination.

I can start the container successfully, but when I try to connect as per the documentation using;
curl http://127.0.0.1:8081
I get;
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

My docker-compose.yml looks like this;

```
services:
  mediawiki:
    container_name: mediawiki
    image: mediawiki:1.40.0-fpm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./images:/var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php

    environment:
      MEDIAWIKI_SITE_SERVER: https://wiki.my.domain
      MEDIAWIKI_SITE_NAME: My Wiki

      # you need to specify the reference to the database, Docker no longer
      # shares environmental variables between linked containers
      MEDIAWIKI_DB_TYPE: mysql # 'mysql' or 'postgres'
      MEDIAWIKI_DB_HOST: db
      MEDIAWIKI_DB_USER: mediawiki
      MEDIAWIKI_DB_PASSWORD: YcBUxyP6tdKfyDEY
      MEDIAWIKI_DB_NAME: mediawiki

      # uncomment 'MEDIAWIKI_ENABLE_SSL' to enable SSL support
      # MEDIAWIKI_ENABLE_SSL: true

    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
    external: true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that dockerised MediaWiki, even its official edition, is already so production-ready that a novice can just take an image and use it. Better build your own image.

Comment: This would seem to make the official images rather useless.